# How do I install the databases and Stockfish chess engine into ChessX?

Tags: software-installation

Recently I installed Ubuntu and then ChessX.  But the databases won't download.  I get a message that they are unavailable at this time.  I also wanted to use Stockfish chess engine and haven't figured out how to download engines into ChessX.

I'm new to Linux, so I'm learning as I go.

Thanks!